# How to fetch data in laravel 5.4 with out using array_push

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

its there's a way to optimize this code. I already google it but I don't know what the exact keyword to search, so I always failed to find the answer.

**At this code I get the Approver List of ID 512 (requestor)**

```
 $approver_list = DB::table('users')
        ->leftjoin('approver_group_list', 'approver_group_list.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->leftjoin('approval_roles', 'approval_roles.as_id', '=', 'approver_group_list.as_id')
        ->leftjoin('approver_requestor_list', 'approver_requestor_list.at_id', '=', 'approval_roles.at_id')
        ->where('approver_requestor_list.user_id', 512)
        ->get();
```

**Then I use array_push to extract the data of approver_list, then I use the value of $result to get value in LeaveMain table.**

```
$result = array();
    foreach($approver_list as $al)
    {
        array_push($result , $al->user_id);
    }
    $leave_list = LeaveMain::whereIn('requestor_id', $result)->get();
```

My problem is, it is always need to use array_push to to extract data, or laravel have a way to optimize this code.

Comment: I think you're better off at [Code review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $approver_list = DB::table('users')
        ->leftjoin('approver_group_list', 'approver_group_list.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->leftjoin('approval_roles', 'approval_roles.as_id', '=', 'approver_group_list.as_id')
        ->leftjoin('approver_requestor_list', 'approver_requestor_list.at_id', '=', 'approval_roles.at_id')
        ->where('approver_requestor_list.user_id', 512)
        ->pluck('id');


$leave_list = LeaveMain::whereIn('requestor_id', $approver_list)->get();
```

Basically you can pluck the id from the table itself, rather than fetching all the data and then taking the id later, and whereIn accepts collection as the second argument. so no need to cast to an array

> The whereIn method filters the collection by a given key / value
>   contained within the given array: [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-wherein)

Comment: ->pluck('users.id')->all();

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop the approver_list values, you can use `pluck` method to retrieves all of the values for user_id.

```
$result = $approver_list->pluck('user_id')->toArray();
$leave_list = LeaveMain::whereIn('requestor_id', $result)->get();
```